# Shooting sequence in shuffled Russian Roulette to remove advantage of going first?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, conditional-probability, game-theory, random-walk

Alice and Bob are playing shuffled Russian Roulette. Starting with Alice, each player takes a turn to throw a dice. The first person to land a 1 (with probability $p=\frac{1}{6}$) is the winner.

But since Alice goes first, she has an advantage. It's not hard to prove her probability of winning is $\frac{6}{11}\approx 0.55$.

To combat this (and try to make it fair 50-50 odds), we adjust the sequence of turns.

Originally, it was ABABABA$\cdots$ (alternating turns).

We might think of changing it to ABBABABABA$\cdots$ (Bob gets 2 turns initially, then it goes back to alternating), but this turns out to give odds in favor of Bob.

My question is: is there a sequence of turns (with Alice's turn first) such that Bob and Alice will have equal odds of winning? Preferably, your answer should be for a generic $p$, not just $1/6$.

Comment: As long as no player has probability $\ge 0.5$ of winning outright in the first $i-1$ turns, you can just give turn $i$ to whichever player has lower odds of winning in the first $i-1$ turns. Since $p < \frac{1}{2}$, that process will never cause either player to have probability of winning outright of $>0.5$ after any finite sequence. But also, if one player's probability of winning outright by turn $i$ is $r$, then the other player will get all the turns until their probability of winning outright exceeds $r$.

Comment: @1Rock +1: to your comment.  I could be mistaken, re I didn't scrutinize it that closely, but it seems to me that your comment qualifies as an **answer**.  Why not delete your comment, and post it as an answer to the query.

Comment: Interesting question. What's its origin?

Comment: @YJT The thought came to me from this [vsauce video](https://youtu.be/Xtl9orvkDVo) about Russian roulette, and simple rules to mitigate the advantage of going first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a simple python program to calculate a sequence of turns. The idea is that $a$ and $b$ are the probabilities of Alice or Bob having won so far. $a$ is initialized to $p$ and $b$ is initialized to 0. At each step, whoever has the lower probability is given the turn. If $c$ is given the turn, their probability is updated as $c = c + p\cdot(1 - a - b)$.

```
    from fractions import Fraction as F # use exact Fraction class because 32-bit floats are too imprecise
    def move(a, b, p):
      if a < b:
        a += p*(1-(a+b))
        return "A", (a, b)
      else:
        b += p*(1-(a+b))
        return "B", (a, b)
    
    n = 500 # number of turns to compute
    p = F(1, 6) # 1/6
    turns = ["A"]
    a = p; b = 0
    for _ in range(n):
      t, (a, b) = move(a, b, p)
      turns.append(t)
    
    print("".join(turns))
```

At the end is the turn order for the first 500 turns. Any insight about this turn order? I've found a way to compute it, but I don't really have a sense of if there's some deeper pattern emerging here.

Turn order for $p=1/6$ (first 500 turns):
ABBABAABBAABBAABBAABBABAABBAABBAABBAABBAABABBAABBABAABBAABBAABBAABABBABAABABBAABBAABBAABBABAABABBAABBABAABBAABBAABBAABBAABABBAABBABAABBAABABBAABBAABBABAABABBAABBABAABABBABAABABBAABBAABBAABBABAABBAABABBAABBABAABBAABABBAABBABAABABBABAABABBABAABABBABAABBAABABBABAABABBABAABBAABABBABAABABBABAABBAABABBAABBABAABABBABAABBAABABBABAABBAABBAABABBABAABBAABBAABBAABABBAABBAABBAABBAABABBAABBAABBAABBABAABBAABABBAABBAABBAABBAABABBABAABBAABBAABABBABAABABBAABBAABBAABBABAABBAABBAABBAABBAABABBAABBABAABBAABBAABABBABAA